# Does HTML5 support cross-window messaging?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

The spec says, that I should be able to use postMessage() on a window object. [Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage), I should be able to do it on an open()'d window, too.

However, I've taken Robert Nyman's postMessage example and tried to make it work [across windows](https://www.escde.net/SupportDownloads/test/postMessagedemo.htm). However, neither IE10 nor Chrome seem to provide the postMessage function for a newly opened window.

```js
var target = … // original declaration
popoutbutton.onclick = function(evt) {
    realWin = window.open(iframeWin.frameElement.src, "window1", "width=600,height=400,status=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes");
    target = realWin;
    target.focus();
};

// …snip…

target.postMessage(myMessage.value, expectorigin); // <-- fails because target.postMessage() is undefined
```

Am I missing something or is this feature simply not there yet?

***- update below -***

The developer preview simply doesn't seem to do that. I tried again with the consumer preview. IE10 (build 8250) does it like expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your example works here on Opera

Comment: Which version of opera are you using? The pop'd out window does not work on my installation ver 11.61.

Comment: Could you create a small JSFiddle demo for us to work with?

Comment: I tried, but jsfiddle wouldn't let me. :( If you copy the code, it should work in any seperate real browser window.  http://jsfiddle.net/jbxf/qJyDt/1/

Comment: @JonnyBest have you changed anything? It's not working now. I'm using 11.61 too.

Comment: Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'target' to object

Error thrown at line 23, column 4 in <anonymous function: form.onsubmit>() [...]

Comment: Sorry Andre, I did change things around before testing. It works in Opera now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get it working in Chrome 15.0.874.121 although in your sample you are calling `target.postMessage` before you have opened the window, although you have skipped whatever code originally sets `target`.

You may also be encountering the issue of calling `postMessage` before the content in the new window has loaded (or at least loaded enough for the event listener to be attached). So the event could be fired off when nothing is actually listening. You may need to add a wait in this scenario to ensure the newly opened window is loaded.

In Internet Explorer 10 I get the error SCRIPT16388: Operation Aborted whenever I try the script - even if I wait 10 seconds.

Comment: How did I miss that before? Verified and working now in Chrome.

Comment: I found this IE10 bug too and it happens when the opened window tries to call the parent and which this one will do a postMessage. The trick to fix this is to wrap the postMessage in a setTimeout 0ms. I will follow up with Internet Explorer to see why this is happening.